# How to cd to directory created by os.makedirs

Tags: linux, python-2.7

I have a python snippet to create a directory using `os.makedirs().`

The directory gets created in the path /tmp. However, I am unable to `cd` to it.
When i try to cd in bash it says `no such file or directory`
I have logged in as root and Permissions look fine to me.

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root   4.0K Sep 26 08:59 test_dir1
```

I am able to see the files that gets created under this directory using `ls` command

```
[root@news-indigo tmp]# ls -l /tmp/test_dir1/domino.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 909 Sep 26 09:34 /tmp/test_dir1/domino.txt
```

I am not sure where am i going wrong. Please advise

```
[root@newindigo tmp]# pwd
/tmp
[root@newindigo tmp]# ls -lah /tmp/test_dir1
ls: cannot access /tmp/test_dir1: No such file or directory
[root@newindigo tmp]# cd /tmp/test_dir1
-bash: cd: /tmp/test_dir1: No such file or directory
[root@newindigo tmp]#
```

Comment: Use `os.chdir()` to change directory

Comment: You can't `cd` in bash? What error do you get?

Comment: @Daviid yes, I cannot cd in bash. it just says `no such file or directory`

Comment: That's weird, can you do `pwd`, `ls -lah`, `ls -lah /tmp/test_dir1` and `cd /tmp/test_dir1` then copy and paste all the output here?

Comment: @Daviid I have copied the output of the commands above

Comment: You're obviosuly not creating the `test_dir1` directory or the OS is cleaning `/tmp` almost instantly

Comment: It doesn't look that way because I can still see the files in the directory by using 'ls -l'.

Comment: Can you do the same commands and add `ls -lah /tmp/test_dir1/domino.txt` at the end?

Comment: @Daviid I get the same output as I have copied above, it is able to find the file.

Comment: Ah, one more thing i noticed now, I m able to access the directory if i copy and paste it and not if I type it. I mean, if i do `cd <copy paste directory name>` I am able to cd into it. But it says no such file or directory when i type it `cd test_dir1` . I am very sure i m not making mistake while typing.

Comment: Do the command that works, then do `cd ..` or `cd` to go to home and try the command that doesn't work. then copy an paste everything here. MAybe there's some character that looks like something but it's a different character or there's some null or invisible character in your python code?